# Using RevTeX for conference procedeeng?

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I want to use RevTeX4-1 class for conference proceeding. However I met a problem with duplicating footnote symbols:

[image]

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,notitlepage,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

%% first abstract:
{
\title{Title of first report}
\author{F. Author}
\email{first@authors.com}
\affiliation{First Affiliation}

\maketitle

\vspace{\columnsep}
\twocolumngrid

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\end{thebibliography}

\onecolumngrid
\vspace{\columnsep}
}


%% second abstract:
{
\title{Title of second report}
\author{S. Author}
\email{second@authors.com}
\affiliation{Second Affiliation}

\maketitle

\vspace{\columnsep}
\twocolumngrid

\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\end{thebibliography}

\onecolumngrid
\vspace{\columnsep}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have multiple abstracts on one page? And are you sure you want to use any footnotes in that case?

Comment: @yo': I don't. But revtex puts `\email{first@authors.com}` in footnotes.

Comment: you can always include the e-mail in the affiliation, or whatever. I just think that the footnote numbering is not the issue here.

Comment: @yo': something like `\affiliation{\normalfont E-mail: \url{second@authors.com}}` might do indeed. With a single drawback that it is numbered like affiliation.

Comment: I don't know, it's up to you to know what you want :)